# Cast from maptype to stringtype loses json formatting, pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, transform

i have a .geojson that i converted to a dataframe using

```
df = geojson_to_dataframe(raw, glob='*.geojson', batch_size=100000)
```

Once that is set up, i need to convert the first column "properties" into a stringtype since pyspark labels it as a map type. To cast it as a string i run this code below.

```
df = df.select(df.properties.cast(StringType()).alias("properties"))
```

The problem i am having is the new column is stripped of all of the quotation marks and the colon is now a "->" and it loses its json formatting. Does anyone know how to convert a map type to string type without losing the json formatting?

The column as a map type before the cast

```
{
"BFE_LN_ID":"01001C_722",
"DFIRM_ID":"01001C",
"NAME":"Alabama",
"ALAND":"131185042550",
}
...
```

The column as a string after the cast

```
[
BFE_LN_ID->01001C_722,
DFIRM_ID->01001C,
NAME->Alabama,
ALAND->131185042550,
]
```

Thank you

Update:
Source geojson data that i converted using the above geojson_to_dataframe() code

| properties | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| {"BFE_LN_ID":"01001C_722","DFIRM_ID":"01001C","NAME":"Alabama","ALAND":"131185042550","Shape_Length":"0.00010778212891927651","AWATER":"4582333181","LEN_UNIT":"Feet","VERSION_ID":"1.1.1.0","GFID":"20140910","INTPTLAT":"+32.7395785","STATENS":"01779775","REGION":"3","FUNCSTAT":"A","DIVISION":"6","GEOID":"01","INTPTLON":"-086.8434469","STATEFP":"01","SOURCE_CIT":"01001C_STUDY1","ELEV":"376.0","V_DATUM":"NAVD88","LSAD":"00","STUSPS":"AL","MTFCC":"G4000"} | {"coordinates": [[-86.46788227456062, 32.487228761833364], [-86.46796895264879, 32.48717204906342], [-86.46797248221748, 32.48716977416143]], "type": "LineString"} |

Code used to get incorrect result

```
def nfhl_string(nfhl):
    df = nfhl
    df = df.select(df.properties.cast(StringType()).alias("properties"))
    return df
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Please share the sample source code and data in text format to reproduce your problem.

Comment: just added. expected output is a json string.